# .dotfiles gitignore not ignoring vim/tmp folder

Tags: vim, git, dotfiles

tmp=.dotfiles/vim/tmp.GITIGNORE=.dotfiles/.gitignore.
I have created a gitignore for vim/tmp inside my .dotfiles but they are not being ignored. My temp folder contains /backup/swap/undo/ and every time I come back to git status the .dotfiles I get over extendedly long temp changes? I'm sure this is something as a new comer to version control I'm missing, could someone pls point me in the right direction?

```
#.gitignore content
*.swp
tmp/
```

Comment: can you improve your question by copying your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: theres only two lines *.swp,tmp/**/*

Comment: *.swp it took the star off the .swp